# tofixed() + 2 acting like tofixed + "2"

Tags: javascript

```
var number = 1.2;
var rounded = number.tofixed() + 2
```

I'm trying to sum tofixed value with any number but using the code above I was schoked of rounded = 12.... I wonder why it doesn't sum and how can fix it?

Here is fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CZaVW/).

Thank you.

Comment: Well, `toFixed` returns a string (as you can see in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)). It doesn't make sense to call that method before the addition. If you want to round the number, use `Math.round` (or `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`).

Comment: You could put the unary `+` operator in front of `number.toFixed()` to convert it on the fly back to a `Number` object: `var rounded = +number.toFixed() + 2;`. But as Felix says, a rounding/flooring/ceiling function is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to round down?  Use `Math.floor` instead of `toFixed`.

```
var number = 1.2;
var floored = Math.floor(number) + 2
```

If you really want a rounded number use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn’t have fixed-point numbers. toFixed [returns a string](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.4.5). The number equivalent is Math.round:

```
Math.round(1.2) + 2 // 3
```

Comment: I also answered with round() but then after reading more on it, round will round 2.49 to 2.5. Not sure if the OP wants that

Comment: What did you read? Works for me: http://ideone.com/S01HpV. The [ES5 spec says](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.15), “Returns the Number value that is closest to *x* and is equal to a mathematical integer”.

Comment: @Huangism `Math.round(2.49)` gives me `2` in the Chrome console, so I am also curious as to where you read this.

Answer (score 3):

`Float.toFixed()` returns a string. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) A string + an int will convert the int to a string and concatenate the two strings. What you want is:

```
(number + 2).toFixed();
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I didn't mention that I need + 2 exactly after rounding.

Comment: This will add exactly 2 to your answer. Adding an int to a float might cause a very small amount of impressision, but as you are rounding it anyway, you'll never notice that. If you want to round before adding 2, Sidnicious' answer might be the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

tofixed method returns the answer as a string, you will have to convert it back to a number if you want to do number math on it.

```
var number = 1.2;
var rounded = parseFloat(number.tofixed()) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 1.2
number= number+2
rounded = number.toFixed() ;
```

tofixed method returns the answer as a string, SO you can add first and then round

Answer (score 0):

Convert the resulting string to integer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    number = 1.2
    rounded = parseInt(number.toFixed()) + 2;
    alert(rounded);
})
```